# Converting angular.json to angular-cli.json?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

So I downgraded my project from Angular 7 to Angular 5, which makes my angular.json file incompatible with Angular 5. I'm looking for the best method to converting my current angular.json file to the angular-cli.json file.

Renaming it does not work, as I always get this error when trying to build: `Unable to find any apps in '.angular-cli.json'.`

Is the best way just to look at the two and compare?

Comment: You need to downgrade your `@angular/cli` too, and match the previous version of package.json. Whatever the reason you're downgraded is, I suggest you solve the other problem instead of trying to downgrade.

Comment: I have done that already. Downgrading is required, there is no way around it for me unfortunately.

Comment: The only way I know of is to use the older version of the CLI to generate the older file format and then manually copy any specific settings that you need.